# How can I get my http URL from the PDF I've uploaded in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, http, url, firebase-storage

[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J7yV.png)

I'm creating a project that needs an http URL instead firebase gave me a gs URL, how can I get the HTTP URL for my uploaded PDF files?

Comment: How did you add these image to Cloud Storage?

Comment: What image? The files that I uploaded on firebase storage?

Comment: He's referring to the PDFs. How did you upload the files to storage?

Comment: Oh, I just clicked upload file and uploaded it directly from my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

In that image, you should see the Name of the file on the right-hand side as a hyperlink.
[image]

So long as a valid access token (bottom of that same side menu) exists, you can access it. Just make sure the URL link includes the access token on the end.

Example: `?alt=media&token=53063556-5482-4c09-bd6f-732533b3bfdb`

Comment: I tried accessing that link but my browser always ends up saying "This site cannot be reached". I tried integrating it into my application and it always crashes when opening the PDF file from the firebase.

Comment: on the URL itself, does it have the token attached? if not, you can manually add it on the end - just make sure it matches the format I have, including the `?`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna access the link manually, just click on the hyperlink of document name on right sidebar.(Ang-katipunan.pdf)

But, if you want to automatically pass that link into a a db doc for example,
You should try make use of getDownloadURL and pass that as a field in the firestore document(if using firestore).

Here's an example of passing a URL of a photo as a "imageURL" field.

```
const imageUpload = async () => {
   const uri = img;
   const childPath = `imgs/${Math.random().toString(36)}`; // This math random is not very imp, just to make sure its generating a random link
   const resp = await fetch(uri);
   const blob = await resp.blob();

   const task = firebase
       .storage()
       .ref()
       .child(childPath)
       .put(blob);

 


      const onTaskCompleted = () => {
               task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) =>{ // this is imp
                   saveImage(snapshot);
                   
               })
      };

      const onTaskError = snapshot => {
          console.log(snapshot);
      };

      task.on("state_changed", onTaskError, onTaskCompleted );

        
   };
```

then

```
const saveImage = (downloadURL) => {
     firebase.firestore()  
     .collection('allImages')
     .add({
     
         downloadURL, //this is the link
         name,

     })
    }
```

Change according to your docs